# Android saving coordinates canvas Drawcircle and display on Different Devices

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

```
class Draw extends View {
    private Paint mPaint;
    public Button mCircles;

    DrawFragment mDrawFragment;
    private Circle mCurrentCircle;
    private List<Circle> mCircle= new ArrayList<>();

    public Draw(Context context){
        this(context,null);
    }

    public Draw(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        mPaint=new Paint();
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        mPaint.setAlpha(80);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        for (Circle circle : mCircle) {
            float x1 = circle.getCenter().x;
            float x2 = circle.getFinal().x;
            float y1 = circle.getCenter().y;
            float y2 = circle.getFinal().y;

            double radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(dpx1 - dpx2, 2) + Math.pow(dpy1 - dpy2, 2));

            float rad = (float) radius;

            canvas.drawCircle(dpx1, dpy1, rad, mPaint);
        }

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mCurrentCircle = new Circle(current);
                mCircle.add(mCurrentCircle);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mCurrentCircle != null) {
                    mCurrentCircle.setFinal(current);
                    invalidate();
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                mCurrentCircle = null;
                invalidate();  break;
        }

    }

    Log.i(TAG, "onTouchEvent: at x="+current.x + ", y =" + current.y);

    return true;
}
```

1.I'm saving these coordinates of circles drawn on canvas and this is to mark damages on a car.
            but when i use these values to display on a bigger device , Circle positions are not intact .. what can be done?

Answer (score 1):

All the coordinates are referenced to a device with a screen determined by pixels and pixels per inches.

- If you wish to use the same information on a different device, you must set a sort of anchor point which works for you as a reference.
- For example, if those circles will be drawn over a background image of a car, you should be able to reference theme to the position of that picture.
- With that information, on any other device, you should be able to redraw those circles on any device based on the fact the coordinates are not referenced to the device but are reference to the car image.

I hope this help you to re think the problem.